# Firebase Android Client to Client Notification Message

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a notification message from client A to client B. I understand that this is possible with the Firebase Android SDK by using the FirebaseMessaging class and the RemoteMessage.Builder. I assume this works fine if both clients are in the foreground. But if one client is in the background this won´t work because with RemoteMessage.Builder you can only create data messages with the methods setData and addData but no notification messages which we need in case one client is in the background. Why is this not possible directly with the SDK?

Comment: *but no notification messages which we need in case one client is in the background* that's not true. Data messages are received in the background, but only if the message contains **no** notification

Comment: sorry, you are right, I completely ignored the fact that you need an XMPP server for upstream messages, which I don´t have

Answer (score 0):

I would use onesignal instead of Firebase , also consider that firebase doesn't supports device to device notification push.... it would be easier i guess..